# Case insensitive search in CQ5 using querybuilder

Tags: aem, predicate, query-builder, jcr

Please suggest on how to implement case insensitive search using querybuilder in CQ5. My code is as below ...

```
paramMap.put("1_property", searchType);
paramMap.put("1_property.value", "%" + searchString + "%");
paramMap.put("1_property.operation", "like");
paramMap.put("2_property", "documentId");
paramMap.put("2_property.operation", "exists");
paramMap.put("3_orderby.sort", "asc");
paramMap.put("p.limit", "0");
```

searchType is the node property
searchString is the string that needs to be matched

Presently, it does a case sensitive search. I tried the solution mentioned here
http://www.wemblog.com/2013/04/how-to-create-custom-query-predicate-in.html
It didnt work out.

Comment: How is this question related to XPath?

Comment: Did you tried the solution mentioned in the link http://www.wemblog.com/2013/04/how-to-create-custom-query-predicate-in.html  in CQ's query debugger tool just go to http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html. See this for reference on how to use it http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/23543240500/how-to-use-cqs-query-debugger-tool. Try something out till you get the exact answer for this. Cheers.

Comment: @yashahuja Yep, tried using custom predicates, not working, dont know what i'm missing out

Comment: You can enable the case insensitive search through the Lucene index - refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRlOO0Jt_cw for more details

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same question and found 3 possible solutions for case-insensitive search using QueryBuilder:

1. **Custom query predicate** you mentioned above.
2. **fulltext** predicate.
   Disadvantage: it's greedy and will find all %your_search_query% matches.
   Details is here: http://maxbarrass.blogspot.com/2014/05/jcr-predicate-operations-in-aem.html
3. **nodename** predicate.
    
   This is workaround and works only if you are searching for *jcr:title* property because in most cases nodename = lowercased and escaped jcr:title. 
   So, you can search for *nodename* instead of *jcr:titl*e property.

Third approach was good for me.

Comment: new link for the blog https://maxbarrass.com/blog/2014/05/27/jcr-predicate-operations-in-aem

Answer (score 2):

With AEM 6.2 (and I think a FP for 6.1) querybuilder now supports case insensitive sorting via `orderby.case=ignore`.

Comment: yep, I have a bunch more options documented here https://github.com/wildone/aem-links/blob/master/querybuilder_cheatsheet.md

Answer (score 0):

@alex
order.case is for ordering results...

@Ignat and @David
4th option uing Xpath :)

```
/jcr:root/etc/tags//element(*, cq:Tag)
[
(jcr:like(fn:lower-case(@jcr:title), '%projects%')) 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was custom predicate.

```
@Component(factory = "com.day.cq.search.eval.PredicateEvaluator/caseinsensitive")
public class CaseInsensitivePredicate extends AbstractPredicateEvaluator {


    @Override
    public String getXPathExpression(Predicate predicate, EvaluationContext context) {
        String property = predicate.get("caseinsensitive");
        String propertyValue = predicate.get("value");
        String operation = predicate.get("operation");

        String result;
        if ("like".equals(operation)) {
            result = "jcr:like(fn:lower-case(@" + property + "), '%" + propertyValue.toLowerCase() + "%')";
        } else {
            result = "fn:lower-case(@" + property + ") = '" + propertyValue.toLowerCase() + "'";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And for your QueryBuilder map you can use it like this:

```
map.put("1_caseinsensitive", "propertyName");
map.put("1_caseinsensitive.value", "searchString");
map.put("1_caseinsensitive.operation", "like");
```