# CQ QueryBuilder API.. why?

Tags: aem, jcr

Why is there need of QueryBuilder API in AEM / CQ when we can use JCR Query API? What does it provide that the former doesn't? Or is it just a non-SQL alternative to JCR API?
We are currently building a module which fetches info from JCR nodes and wanted to know the best way to go about it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Query Builder is built on top of JCR Query API. What does query builder provide that JCR API doesn't ? IMHO it would be **Usability**. You deal with a map of predicates instead of queries. The Out of the box predicates work in most situations. The limit and offset features work like a charm for pagination situations. **Grouping** let's you write complex queries in a very readable manner. One more nice feature is the **faceted** search , your search results can be split by tags. Query Builder returns **Resources** and not nodes so you don't have to handle to deal with those checked repository exceptions that come along with JCR api ( https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/cq5-coding-patterns-sling-vs-jcr-part-1/ ).

Since it is exposed as a REST servlet it is often used in building interfaces like custom dashboards and the familiarity helps.

It's an abstraction so you are shielded from changes at lower level. Some of the queries that used to work in JackRabbit 2 don't work in the newer Oak (Aem 6) but all the query builder one's still work.

Faceted search example :

[http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?*charset*=UTF-8&facets=on&isURL=on&query=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4502%2Fbin%2Fquerybuilder.json%3Ftype%3Dcq%3APage%26tagid%3Dmarketing%3Ainterest%2Fproduct%26tagid.property%3Djcr%3Acontent%2Fcq%3Atags](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?_charset_=UTF-8&facets=on&isURL=on&query=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4502%2Fbin%2Fquerybuilder.json%3Ftype%3Dcq%3APage%26tagid%3Dmarketing%3Ainterest%2Fproduct%26tagid.property%3Djcr%3Acontent%2Fcq%3Atags)

Query Builder Details : http://www.slideshare.net/alexkli/cq5-querybuilder-adapttoberlin-2011

Comment: The downside to QueryBuilder IMO is that it is not as fully featured as the JCR API. For example if you want to do a case insensitive order of results by a property you'll have trouble with Querybuilder... whereas in SQL2 you can use `order by lower(propertyName)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878727/case-insensitive-search-in-cq5-using-querybuilder

Comment: With AEM 6.2 (and I think a FP for 6.1) querybuilder now supports case insensitive sorting via `orderby.case=ignore`.